# ASP.NET: parse url having # (hash) sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to parse url that has something after # (hash) sign in my asp.net application. How to do it easily?
Thank you,

Comment: You mean an arbitrary string or the current request?

Comment: please explain what do you want to do. Parsing is too wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I meant fragment (after #) part on the server... Though I've looked thrugh and found that it seems to be impossible......

Comment: If you have more info you should either update your question, or add a comment as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `Uri` class:

```
new Uri(someString).Fragment
```

Note that the hash is not sent to the server in an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

```
url.Substring(url.IndexOf('#') + 1)
```

...where "url" is a string containing the url in question

Answer (score 1):

This is called "hash sign" URI.
After client gets PAGE responsed including js,
the contents after '#' would be handled by client using responsed js to get "real" URL for redirection.
SEE: https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/2011/01/HashInURI-20110115#References