# How to parse access token from URL

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, access-token

I get the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/facebook/Status#access_token=dsadsa
```

I trying parse it in method Status() but variable "Request.Url" is

```
http://localhost:8080/facebook/Status
```

How to solve this problem ?

```
 public ActionResult Status()
        {
            FacebookOAuthResult result;                
            if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(Request.Url, out result))
            {
                if (result.IsSuccess)
                {
                    var accessToken =  result.AccessToken;
                    var code = result.Code;
                    var app = new FacebookClient(fbm.appID, fbm.appSecret);
                    fbm.accessToken = app.AccessToken;
                    ViewData["accessToken"] = app.AccessToken;
                    fbm.isAuthorized = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    var errorDesc = result.ErrorDescription;
                    var errorReason = result.ErrorReason;
                    fbm.isAuthorized = false;
                    ViewData["errorDesc"] = errorDesc;
                    ViewData["errorReason"] = errorReason;
                }       
            }          
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: access_token=dsadsa is part of the query string try using request.querystring["access_token"]

Comment: Request.QueryString is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here [ASP.NET: parse url having # (hash) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743220/asp-net-parse-url-having-hash-sign) that the request object does not contain the hash tag.